# jquery get data from xml into array?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, jqgrid

I'm learning about Jquery and I'm using JqGrid to manipulate my data.
My grid fills perfectly with data from a php file 'admin_db', that "convert" its data into a xml file, like this:

```
//php file        
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        $s .= "<row id='". $row['id_alum']."'>";            
        $s .= "<cell>". $row['id_alum']."</cell>";
        $s .= "<cell>". $row['name']."</cell>";
        $s .= "</row>";
    }

        $s .= "</rows>"; 

        echo $s;
```

I need to get 'id_alum' and 'name' into an array, but when I tried with this function to get data from 'name', nothing happens:

```
  type: "GET",  
  url: "admin_db.php",  
  dataType: "xml",      
  $(xml).find('name').each(function(){...}
```

I hope that you can help me with my problem, I really need to get my data into an array.
Thank you in advance =)
(Sorry if my english is bad, I'm still learning)

Comment: Your current code looks for tags named 'name'. Since all your tags are named 'cell' you'd have to look for the third cell in each row to get at the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
    type: "GET",
    url: "admin_db.php",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
            var id_alum = $(this).find('cell:eq(0)').text();
            var name = $(this).find('cell:eq(1)').text();
        })
    }
```

It's just a quick one... :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll try immediately!

Comment: `$(function(){ 
 url:'lista_bd.php', 
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
 success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('row').each(function(){
            var id_alum = $(this).find('cell:eq(0)').text();
            var name = $(this).find('cell:eq(1)').text();
  }}
});
`
This function doesn´t save anything, so when I try to refference the variables, they appear empty. Any help would be apprecieted.